# Searching games by chess positions

Tags: problems, books, puzzles, master-games, chess-ai

I have a somewhat weird question that is only indirectly related to chess. I am trying to solve a chess-related puzzle in which I have to find games played by Soviet chess players based on positions. There are six positions given as images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone recommend me some online database that would be able to find the corresponding games and would not be behind a paywall, if that exists at all? Then, would any AI algorithm be able to recognize such images and convert them to some standard format like PGN, or that still needs to be done manually?

Answer (score 4):

I used the [Chessvision.ai Chess Position Scanner](https://chessvision.ai/) extension to scan the images and get the position FENs, then with the help of [CQL](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/fen.html), I searched [Mega Database](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/mega_database_2024) and found these games:

- [Tigran Petrosian vs Mikhail Botvinnik](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1032639) at the World Championship Match (1963).
- [Leonid Stein vs Tigran Petrosian](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1106505) at the USSR Championship 1961a (1961).
- [Yuri Averbakh vs Alexander Kotov](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1084375) at Zuerich Candidates (1953).
- [Vasily Smyslov vs Mikhail Tal](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1125953) at 4th Soviet Team Cup (1964).
- [Slim Bouaziz vs Efim Geller](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1049309) at Sousse Interzonal (1967).
- [Mark Taimanov vs Roman Dzindzichashvili](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1040018) at 12th Soviet Team Championship Final-A (1972).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. I was already starting to lose hope of getting an answer here.